# Why is Intellij code auto completion in JSF with Primefaces not working?

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have installed intellij IDEA Ultimate Edition latest version and started to test the compatibility of it with primefaces version 6.2.
If it could be compatible with primeface we are gonna switch from eclips to intellij.
unfortunatly i cann't figure out how to get code autocomplition to work for primefaces.
I have done alreaday the following.

1. created maven project.
2. added primeface dependency in pom.
3. Added primeface framework by right clicking on the project and choosing Add framework support....

**Does any one know how to fix this issue?**

**Does anyone know the best IDEA for working with primeface?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did solve it by the following. I got inspiration from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/jsf-facet-page.html).

1. Added primeface framework by right clicking on the project and choosing Add framework support....
2. Added JSF facet to my web modules from `File | Project Structure | Modules - module - JSF facet Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S`
3. Restarting intellij IDEA

Comment: Did it really need a restart? There you go. If there is a will, there is a way. :). It would have been preferred if this was somehow automatically scanned directly from the POM - the current way it works seems slightly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly looking into this issue revealed this link, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-for-jsf-application-development.html.

The website states that in order to enable support for JSF development, you need the *Ultimate edition*.

I would suggest taking a look at NetBeans. It is continuously developed alongside new implementations of Java EE (and soon Jakarta EE) and is therefore the go-to IDE environment for JavaEE development.  Everything works pretty much out of the box.

Comment: Could you please at least make sure your answer is relevant before starting to pitch a competing product? OP said that they added PrimeFaces through "Add framework support". That feature is only available in IntelliJ Ultimate, too. So they are already using it.

Comment: No need to start trolling. I wouldn't know exactly what and what doesn't work and exactly what is missing in the normal edition. The question does not make it clear that they are using the Ultimate Edition or not. I consider my answer relevant as NetBeans is developed alongside Java EE and tends to fully support everything it offers. There is no harm in recommending an alternative when it's actually better for the task.

Comment: If you don't know much about IntelliJ IDEA, then why are you answering questions on its use, and how do you know whether it's good for the task?\

Comment: I never said I never tried IntelliJ. There's a reason I don't use it for JavaEE development.